# Does it take some time to start and stop Stopwatch?

Tags: c#, wpf, time, stopwatch

I have a very specific question that I need answered for a very specific performance test. I will simplify the code, to make it easier understandable.

I do many calculations (a few ten million), all done in loops that are themselves not too long and I need the total calculation time. However, all the calculations are not done directly one after another and some extra code "comes inbetween" every loop.

What I need, is quite exactly the total time of all loops (including declaring and initializing i, incrementing it, and comparison with 100 in exmaple). To measure the time I start a `Stopwatch` directly before every loop and stop it directly after the loop. But do those two actions need some time that might be relevant?

**Example:**

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
//how long does it now take until for loop is reached?
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //some calculations
}
//how much time does it take to stop sw?
sw.Stop();
```

Of course it wouldn't really matter if all the loops were done directly one after another, I could just start at the beginning of the first loop and stop at the end of the last one, but that is not possible here.

I know the question is very specific, but I hope someone can help me here, as a significant time coming from around fifty million loops, could in a way affect my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could try this and check it on your own, on my (lousy performing ) computer it's about 0.0006 milliseconds for the first execution and 0.0001 milliseconds for next executions. Try it yourself:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(sw.ElapsedTicks);
string elapsed = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the StopWatch-Stopwatch typo. I am just used to use `Stopwatch StopWatch = new Stopwatch();` and somehow used capital W.

To your answer: Thanks, I have thought of doing it this way but thought, it might be "a different situation". However, as a checking, I will probably run your code a few thousand times and average over the time.

Answer (score 4):

> What I need, is quite exactly the total time of all loops. To measure the time I start a StopWatch directly before every loop and stop it directly after the loop. But do those two actions need some time that might be relevant?

They take some time - as does the initialization of `i`, and the increment, and the comparison with 100 in each loop iteration. Almost nothing is *instantaneous* in computing.

Whether it's *relevant* or not is another matter. Unless your calculation is utterly trivial, it's unlikely that this will be significant in your timing. You could *try* timing an empty loop, but it's possible that the JIT compiler will get rid of the loop itself entirely.

Comment: Everything is relevant (initialization of i, increment, comparison) except for the actual time to reach the for-loop. The calculations are quite trivial (sometimes just a couple of additions) and sometimes the loops are very short (around 10 iterations).
I thought that was implied, I will update my question.

Comment: @phil13131: At that point, it becomes very hard to get any genuine measure of performance. As I say, you could *try* the empty loop - or try the smallest non-trivial operation which avoids the JIT compiler optimizing it away - to find a base result. But fundamentally, it sounds like the answer is, "Yes, the actions take some time." Note that it would help if you'd call the `Start` and `Stop` methods (possibly on a different instance) beforehand, so they'll be JIT-compiled. (Otherwise that JIT-compilation could be part of what you measure...)

Comment: Thanks, for mentioning the JIT-compilation, but when you reach the method `sw.Start()` shouldn't at that point the code be already compiled?

Comment: @phil13131: Not necessarily. I wouldn't like to say without checking. (The method you're running in will have been compiled, but `Start` and `Stop` might not have been...)